# How to remove one item for Sending the User to Another App in android?

Tags: android

How can i remove Google+ from the intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
...

// Always use string resources for UI text.
// This says something like "Share this photo with"
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
// Create intent to show chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

[image: all items]

How can i remove Google+ from the intent?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Intent> targetIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent templateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
templateIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> packages = this.getPackageManager().
        queryIntentActivities(templateIntent, 0);

// remove desired package
for (ResolveInfo candidate : packages) {
    String packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName;
    if (!packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus")) { //GooglePlus Package name
        Intent target = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        target.setType("text/plain");
        target.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Text Here");
        target.setPackage(packageName);
        targetIntents.add(target);
    }
}
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetIntents.remove(0), "Share.");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```